# Bullet point with different color on OpenOffice Writer

Tags: colors, openoffice, openoffice-writer

I've found myself in need to do something I've never though about before.

I needed to put a different color on some bullets.

I've found a way to do this, but I find it so hacky...
(It's a very unreliable way.)

What I do is simple:

- Fill the list with your text
- Change the text color for that bullet, using the color you want
- Put a space before the text
- Manually select the whole text *except* the space
- Change the text color to the color you want it to be.

As you can see, it is a bit hacky.

Here is the result:

[image]

This method actually works after saving, but it may be changed in the future or may not work on older version (I have the version 4.1.1).

Is there a better way to achieve the same result, but reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advice to use manual bullets + space / tabulation.

You can find bullet symbol in "Character Map" or in OpenOffice Writer top menu "Insert" -> "Special Symbols" or by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>. After releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd> you will get • symbol insert.

And you are free to color them the way you actually want without any pain and version support.
[image]

Comment: Why didn't I though about the bullet point char? It really is a neat feat, but it won't help with other things that lists can do. Unless you use tabs and select different tab points. But it really is a nice trick and I give you points for that!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can't figure another way to do this. Hope this helps a bit. Good luck with that :)

Comment: It really did help! Sadly, I can't use your method since I require the list's 'goodies'. Like the automatic alignment when you make a new line and the correct alignment when a line if text 'overflows'. Unless I somehow manage to make invisible bullet points. Then this method would be great. Or a table, which would achieve most of the features I need.

Comment: Invisible bullets points is a good idea.

Comment: The only question is "How?", but Google has the answer, I'm sure.

Comment: What's the problem? Just click on the bullet and choose white color.